# How to initialize QXmlStreamWriter with QString as member variable?

Tags: c++, qt, constructor, streamwriter, qtxml

I have implemented my own xml writer to generate xml as QString.

i have create a class "MyXmlWriter" with private member variable as QXmlStreamWriter and try to initialize it in the public method writeToString()

in declaration header file:

```
class MyXmlWriter {
  public:
    MyXmlWriter();
    ~MyXmlWriter();
    QString writeToString();
  private:
    QXmlStreamWriter writer;
    void writePart();
}
```

in cpp file:

```
void MyXmlWriter::writePart() {
   // i want to use the QXmlStreamWriter instance hier
}
QString MyXmlWriter::writeToString(){
   QString result;
   writer(&result); // at this became the error: no match for call to '(QXmlStreamWriter) (QString*)'
   xmlWriter.setAutoFormatting(true);
   // private method called 
   writePart();

   return result;
}
```

this error appear on build:
***error: no match for call to (QXmlStreamWriter) (QString*) writer(&result); ***

If the *QXmlStreamWriter write* is declared in the local method *writeToString()* then i cant access this writer in private method *writePart()*
i want to use the member variable "writer" in other methods that's why a local declaration isn't an option for me.

Comment: "_QXmlStreamWriter and try to initialize it in the public method writeToString()_" It is initialized before entering the constructor `MyXmlWriter::MyXmlWriter`, and only then. If such variable meant to be local to the method `writeToString`, why is it a member variable? If it is meant to be member variable - initialize it in the constructor.

Comment: how can i initialize it in constructor and get access too from other methods like writeToString ?

Comment: @M.Saad You have `QString result;` member of the class, at the moment it is a local variable that is eliminated when it finishes executing the function where it was created.

Comment: @eyllanesc the ```QString result; ``` is locally defined to be returned as QString.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign a new object to your variable `writer`, like this:

```
QString MyXmlWriter::writeToString() {
    QString result;
    writer = QXmlStreamWriter(&result);  // will not compile
    return result;
}
```

**This code is dangerous.** `result` is destroyed at the end of `writeToString()`, so `writer` then contains invalid data and you cannot use it anymore.

Additionally, `QXmlStreamWriter` cannot be copied, so this would probably not compile at all. It's better to just pass the `QXmlStreamWriter` to your methods, like this:

```
class MyXmlWriter {
  public:
    MyXmlWriter();
    ~MyXmlWriter();
    QString writeToString();
  private:
    void writePart(QXmlStreamWriter &writer);
}
```

and

```
QString MyXmlWriter::writeToString() {
    QString result;
    QXmlStreamWriter writer(&result);

    writePart(writer);
    writePart(writer);

    return result;
}
```